# Can no longer get the ElementType a field is attached to

Tags: plugin-development, entry-type

I wrote a simple fieldtype that checks that the field value is unique for a specific entry type: https://github.com/fuel-digital/Craft-Unique-Text-FieldType

This worked fine initially but after the recent core updates, $this->element in the valueExists() method is null on new entries, where previously it was an instance of ElementType::Entry or whatever else the field was attached to.

While I could instantiate a new ElementType::Entry object if one doesn't exist, this limits the field's use to Entries, and not Assets, Users etc.

Is there some other way of getting the element's value now? I can't see anything when inspecting the field class.

Comment: `$this->element` won't necessarily be set depending on the context your field type is used in, so your field type needs to be aware of that. That's always been the case, too, so I doubt a recent update changed anything related to that.

Comment: Weird, as it was fine in testing until recently. Any suggestions on how I can achieve what I'm looking to do?